# Java comma "," in forEach

Tags: java, foreach, java-8

I have got a little problem with printing out comma in my java project. In `forEach` section the program is always printing out "," > even after the last word... see output

```
.listener("lookAround", (Game g, String action, AbstractGameObject object, Object retVal) -> {
    System.out.print("You see: \n\t");

    if (g.getItemsInRoom((Room) object).isEmpty() && g.getDoorsInRoom((Room) object).isEmpty())
       System.out.print("nothing");

    g.getItemsInRoom((Room) object)
                     .stream()
                     .forEach(item -> System.out.print(item.getName() + ", "));

    g.getDoorsInRoom((Room) object)
                     .stream()
                     .forEach(door -> System.out.print(door.getName() + ", "));
    System.out.println("\n");
})
```

The output:

```
You see:    
Black Wooden door, Brown Wooden door,
```

I would like output:

```
You see:    
Black Wooden door, Brown Wooden door
```

Is there a easy way to solve this problem ?
Thank you for a help :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you should be printing inside that `forEach` lambda. Actually I'm not even sure you should be using the `stream` API there.

Think about using [String.join()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-) or the [`StringJoiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) class instead.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `StringJoiner` directly, rather than via the `Stream` API, let’s you handle the empty case without additional code:

```
StringJoiner j=new StringJoiner(", ").setEmptyValue("nothing");
g.getItemsInRoom((Room)object).forEach(o -> j.add(o.getName()));
g.getDoorsInRoom((Room)object).forEach(o -> j.add(o.getName()));
System.out.println("You see: \n\t"+j);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution helped a lot :)